# Rails relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to figure out something regarding rails relationships. I already posted a question regarding a specific items not long ago but I do not really understand what's done in the underlying DB.

I have a `Project` model and a `Client` model.
A Project `belongs_to :client` => I need to manually add `client_id` in projects table (with a migration).
A `Client` `has_many :projects` => I do not need to do anything in the DB (no migration).
The `project.client` and `client.projects` methods are both available.

I have a `Group` model and a `User` model.
A `Group` `has_and_belongs_to_many :user`
A `User` `has_and_belongs_to_many :group`
I then need to create a migration to create a joint table with a `user_id` and a `group_id` pointers.

I do not really see where the border between rails and the relational database is.
Why do I need to add foreign key sometimes but not always ? How is the `has_many` relationship handled as I did not do anything in the underlying DB for this particuliar guy ?

I am kind of lost sometimes :)

Thanks and Regards,

Luc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a `has_many` <-> `belongs_to` assoication, you're defining that one project is owned (`belongs_to`) by one client. Therefore, that client has many (`has_many`) projects. For a project to determine what client it belongs to it needs to have an `client_id` column so that it can look it up. This `client_id` column is used by Rails when you call the `client` method, much like this:

```
Client.find(project.client_id)
```

That's how you can find a project's client. The `client_id` column is often referred to as a *foreign key*, because its a unique identifier ("key") in a table not of its origin ("foreign"). Boom.

When you call the other way around, finding all the projects a client has, i.e. `client.projects`, Rails does the equivalent of this:

```
Project.find_all_by_client_id(client.id)
```

This then returns all `Project` records which are associated with a particular client, based off the `client_id` field in the `projects` table.

---

With a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association, such as your users & groups example, you're declaring that a user `has_and_belongs_to_many :groups`.

Now if it were simply a `has_many :groups`, the foreign key would go in the `groups` table, or if it were a `belongs_to` it would go in the `users` table. Good thing to remember: the foreign key always goes in the table of the model that has the `belongs_to`.

You're also declaring that a group `has_and_belongs_to_many :users`, and so we come across the same problem. We can't declare the key in the users table because it doesn't belong there (because a user has many groups, you would need to store all the group ids the user belongs to) or the groups table for the same reasons.

This is why for a `has_and_belongs_to_many` we need to create what's known as a *join table*. This table has two and only two fields (both of them foreign keys), one for one side of the association and another for the other. To create this table, we would put this in a migration's `self.up` method:

```
create_table :groups_users, :id => false do |t|
  t.integer :group_id
  t.integer :user_id
end
```

A couple of things to note here:

1. The table name is the two names of the two associations in alphabetical order. G comes before U and so the table name is `groups_users`.
2. There's the `:id` option here which, when given the value of `false` generates a table with no primary key. A join table doesn't need a primary key because its purpose is to just join other tables together.
3. We store the `group_id` and `user_id` as integer fields, just like we would on a `belongs_to` association.

This table will then keep track of what groups have what users and vice versa.

There's no need to define additional columns on either the `users` or `groups` table because the join table has got that under control.

Comment: thanks a lot, this very clear. Just one thing, Client.find(project.client_id) is the same has project.client, right ? What about client.projects ? Is this method created by the has_many statement only ?

Answer (score -1):

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders, dependent: :destroy
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end

@order = @customer.orders.create(order_date: Time.now)
```